# Error upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, update

I needed to restore a database (created in SQL Server 2008 R2 - version 10.50.1600) to a new DB in Server 2008 (version - 10.00.2531). I got the error - **Restore failed for Server ....**

```
Additional info
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server 
running version 10.50.1600. That incompatible with the server which is 
running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that 
supports the backup or use a backup that is compatible with the server.
```

So I downloaded the SQL Server 2008 R2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3743), and updated the 2008 version of the server to 2008 R2. The update process was successful.

Then I downloaded the SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985&hash=0rAV89qTyMsHVnuiXYbjZBOEVHi/GkMVkpxLrXFV/czyH3VE0H3Ccw3sMsSw9ObL/c/VAeMq2k/WtyeR40zdUg==) and tried to update the MSE. It raised the following error!

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup
------------------------------

The following error has occurred:

An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransferStoredProceduresTask,fileVersion="10.50.1600.1",version="10.0.0.00000",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. 

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xF45F6601%25401201%25401

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Now, there is a folder for R2 in 'Programs' of Start menu. 
[image]

But only version 10.00.2531 is available in management studio! 
[image]

What should I do? (my main goal is to restore the database!)

(The backup was created in a 64 bit machine while the machine I'm currently working (trying to restore the DB) is a 32 bit one; and I used the correct versions (x86) of setups - server and management studio.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly may be issues with 64 bit versions versus 32 and trying to restore backwards. You might ultimately find the best solution is to build a temporary 64 bit 2008 r2 virtual machine  or clone an existing known good box to do your restore. Instead of trying to force these types of products to your bidding, I've had less frustration doing it the "ms" way.

Comment: I'm thinking about taking backups of all the DB's and then uninstalling the existing 2008 instances (both SQL server and Management Studio); Then installing fresh copies of SQL Server 2008 R2 and Mgt Studio (32 bit versions). How's this sound?

Comment: Yeah i think that is heading in the right direction. I amalways paranoid so if i were you if possible to a bare metal backup of the entire server before backingup databases and UNinstalling. If the db backup is bad you may not find out until everything has been erased.

Comment: Well, the machine I'm talking about is just an "extra resource" machine used mostly for R&D. So, there's only some test data in the DB's, which are not that important. But restoring the specific DB I mentioned earlier is really important for me right now. So I think I'll go with the fresh install.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: How did it go? please post results.

Comment: Installed R2 server and Mgt studio. All the issues are solved!